# Automatic popup of words from the buffer using Corfu and Dabbrev

Tags: init-file, auto-complete-mode, popup, dabbrev, corfu

How can I make Dabbrev and Corfu automatically show a pop-up for the words from my current buffer? For example, if I write "example" somewhere in a document, I would like it pops up automatically when I start writing "exa". I have Corfu-global-mode corfu-pop-up mode and Corfu-history enabled.

**However, this popup suggestion works perfectly on org-mode! For any other modes, it just does not work. It would be very helpful to get it to work for other modes, especially for Latex mode and Python mode!**

Please let me know. Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is my config for corfu:

```
(use-package corfu
    :custom
    (corfu-cycle t)                 ; Allows cycling through candidates
    (corfu-auto t)                  ; Enable auto completion
    (corfu-auto-prefix 2)
    (corfu-auto-delay 0.1)
    (corfu-popupinfo-delay '(0.4 . 0.2))
    (corfu-preview-current 'insert) ; Do not preview current candidate
    (corfu-preselect-first nil)
    (corfu-on-exact-match nil)      ; Don't auto expand tempel snippets

    :bind (:map corfu-map
                ("M-SPC"      . corfu-insert-separator)
                ("TAB"        . corfu-next)
                ([tab]        . corfu-next)
                ("S-TAB"      . corfu-previous)
                ([backtab]    . corfu-previous)
                ("S-<return>" . nil) ;; leave my entry as it is
                ("RET"        . corfu-insert))

    :init
       (global-corfu-mode)
       (corfu-history-mode)
       (corfu-popupinfo-mode) ; Popup completion info
    )
  (add-hook 'tex-mode-hook #'corfu-mode)
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'corfu-mode)
```

Comment: You do not need the two hooks if you use `global-corfu-mode`. Please check whether autocomplete works without that for LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue was with Eglot in prog mode. I had to add `cape-dabbrev` to `eglot-managed-hook` as a `cape-super-capf` in addition to adding `cape-dabbrev` to the `completion-at-point-functions` list.

```
(defun my/eglot-capf ()
(setq-local completion-at-point-functions
(list (cape-super-capf
#'cape-dabbrev
#'eglot-completion-at-point (cape-company-to-capf #'company-yasnippet)
#'tempel-expand
#'cape-file
))))
(add-hook 'eglot-managed-mode-hook #'my/eglot-capf)
```

I hope this helps anyone who might be struggling with the issue!